# Dual monitor setup on a Radeon RX 470 (total resolution 4480x1080)

Tags: graphics-cards, video, multiple-monitors, video-adapters

My actual single screen setup is an Asus ROG Strix Radeon RX 470 Gaming OC 4GB GDDR5 (2x DVI-D, 1x HDMI, 1x DisplayPort 1.2; max resolution 5120x2880) on which I have connected an 21:9 2560x1080 screen.

While this was ok and offered me a lot of possibilities (like simultaneous dual half-screen windows with **huge** viewport size or cinematic movies without black boxes) I need to increase my working space for sake of productivity and I'm currently planning on get a second Full HD monitor.

This is for a personal setup, so I often use my current monitor for gaming (assume Windows 10), but I would need the second monitor to track other activities as well.

So my questions are:

- Can I plug a second monitor on another of the available video outputs and work with it simultaneously?
- If not, could I use the DisplayPort output with a signal splitter? Which one would you recommend?
- If none of the above, I guess I should upgrade my GPU. Any recommendation under 300€ that would fit my needs?